# Error parenthesis in c#,why?

Tags: c#

Why do I get errors in parenthesis? 
thank you
https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=B71B2418AA133D20&resid=B71B2418AA133D20%211722&authkey=AGhuiPOEiWrvNLI

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                                           //ERROR!!!
         public static class Calcolatrice
    {
        public static int Somma (int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        public static int Sottrazione (int x, int y)
        {
            return x - y;
        }



    }
    int i = Calcolatrice.Somma(12, 3);
    int j = Calcolatrice.Sottrazione(45, 34);
    }
}
```

Comment: Classes cannot be declared inside methods.

Comment: next time, post your code in your question and do not put a link to a screen shot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your code in the question, screenshots are not very helpful in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined your class inside your Main method. You need to define your class outside of this, perhaps in a new file.

Comment: Sorry, I've never posted to the forum, I did not know I had to post the code into the post. 
Thanks for the replies. 
I have another question: 
To create an output to the screen as I do? I do not accept the statement "Console.WriteLine ()" and even "Console.ReadLine ()".

Comment: @GuglielmoAstro If you want to ask a different question - you should not put it in a comment - you should use the ask question button. As before, if you put in the code, we will look at it. These are the rules unfortunately - but they are designed to help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected it for you:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {           var i = Calcolatrice.Somma(12, 3);
        var j = Calcolatrice.Sottrazione(45, 34);
    }

    public static class Calcolatrice
    {
        public static int Somma(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        public static int Sottrazione(int x, int y)
        {
            return x - y;
        }
    }
}
```